# how to validate asp textbox placed inside jquery template

Tags: c#, jquery-templates

i have an asp:textbox inside my jquery template given below

```
<script id="ProjectTypeTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">

<tr id="trProjType">
 <td>${lang_id} </td>
 <td><input id="${lang_id}" type="text" /> <span class="RequiredFieldStar">*</span></td>
  <td>${merchant_id}</td>
 <td>${lang_id}</td>
 <td>${name_lang}</td>

</tr>

</script>
```

i have to do validation for it something like this

```
 <div id = "Projtypediv">

                                        <table id = "project_type_templ_tbl"     border="1" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;"> 

                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator     ID="reqvProjectTypeDescription" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter Project Type     Description"
                                                            ControlToValidate="Id of the inputbox" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>     <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender
                                                            runat="Server" ID="vceProjectTypeDescription" TargetControlID="reqvProjectTypeDescription" />

                                                    <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="custvProjectTypeDescription" ErrorMessage="Enter characters except (<,>,&#,\) in Project Type Description"
                                                        ControlToValidate="Id of the inputbox" Display="None" ClientValidationFunction="checkSpecialCharacter" />

                                                    <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender runat="Server" ID="vceSpCharacterProjectTypeDescription"
                                                        TargetControlID="custvProjectTypeDescription" />

                                    </table>
                                    </div>
```

where project_type_templ_tbl is the name of the table that contains the template

thanx for the help in advance

Comment: Triggering validation by javascript is a case for you or are you looking for a solution using server side C#?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple JavaScript script to trigger validators.

Move validators you are need in the same validation group by adding an attribute `ValidationGroup="YourCustomGroupName"` and then you can use JS method:

```
Page_ClientValidate(“YourCustomGroupName”))
```

Comment: thanx sll for the help but i hav a doubt the id of the textbox wil be now like this  <td><asp:TextBox ID="ProjectTypeDesc_${lang_id}" runat="server" Width="70%"> </asp:TextBox><span  class="RequiredFieldStar">*</span></td>
  how do i do validation now

Comment: No matter which Id of a Textbox, you should know which validators are aware of this particular textBox so add them into the same ValidationGroup group

Comment: BTW, you are using Custom Validator which provides you a ClientValidationFunction, is it wont work for you?

Comment: how does it validate the textbox whose id keeps onchanging..i think it is not possible because controltovalidate for required field validator keeps on changing

Comment: pls check the question i have made an edit for the textbox and the custom field validator was not wrking

Comment: So really you don't have as.pnet textbox control? So regular validators wont' work in this case